# Object creation method confused

Tags: php, object

I have read the manual for this point but I cannot understand the logic behind this. 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

```
$obj1 = new Test();
$obj2 = new $obj1;

var_dump($obj1 === $obj2); //bool(false)
```

How this happen even though,

```
var_dump($obj1); //object(Test)#1 (0) { } 
var_dump($obj2); //object(Test)#2 (0) { }
```

I expect the bool(true) but it is "bool(false)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php):-

> when using the identity operator (===), object variables are identical if and only if they refer to the same instance of the same class

You have two **separate** instances of the same class, so `===` evaluates to false.

So, `$obj1 === $obj2` evaluates to false, but `$obj1 == $obj2` would evaluate to true as

> When using the comparison operator (==), object variables are compared in a simple manner, namely: Two object instances are equal if they have the same attributes and values, and are instances of the same class.

It may be that you are unaware that you have created a new instance of Test by doing `$obj2 = new $obj1;`. Change this to `$obj2 = $obj1;` and you will find that `$obj1 === $obj2` evaluates to true as you now have two variables refering to the same instance of Test.

Comment: Thanks both for explaining me the answer and not f***g down voting my question. :)

Comment: @Priyanga No problem. But this is all explained clearly in the manual, so I imagine that is the reason for the down votes. Don't sweat it, it happens.

Comment: @Priyanga Follow the link at the top of my answer.

Comment: @vascowhte Can you give me your blog to follow your php articlas?

Comment: @Priyanga I don't have a blog and I have never written a PHP article in my life. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Objects are only equivelent if they refer to the same instance.

```
$obj1 = new Test();
$obj2 = new Test();
var_dump($obj1 === $obj2); // bool(false)
```

But

```
$obj1 = new Test();
$obj2 = &$obj1;
var_dump($obj1 === $obj2);  // bool(true)
```